# Retrieving specific data from list/dictionary

Tags: typescript, list, discord.js

```
[
  '854408347192786944',
  Message {
    id: '854408347192786944',
    type: 0,
    timestamp: 1623777224110,
    channel: TextChannel {
      id: '768848054064644156',
      type: 0,
      client: [Client],
      guild: [Guild],
      name: 'dev-chat',
      position: 23,
      parentID: '768835234291777556',
      permissionOverwrites: [Collection [Map]],
      rateLimitPerUser: 0,
      topic: null,
      messages: [Collection [Map]],
      lastMessageID: '854408347192786944',
      lastPinTimestamp: null
    },
    content: 'nittro',
    hit: false,
    reactions: {},
    guildID: '768551672195710997',
    messageReference: null,
    flags: 0,
    author: User {
      id: '585548631268917254',
      bot: false,
      system: false,
      avatar: '902e633f0c1af22ee6eff4f114b533c1',
      username: '8au',
      discriminator: '0489',
      publicFlags: 128
    },
    referencedMessage: null,
    interaction: null,
    member: Member {
      id: '585548631268917254',
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      game: [Object],
      nick: null,
      roles: [Array],
      joinedAt: 1603307397735,
      premiumSince: null,
      pending: false,
      status: 'online',
      clientStatus: [Object],
      activities: [Array]
    },
    mentionEveryone: false,
    mentions: [],
    roleMentions: [],
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    attachments: [],
    embeds: []
  }
]
```

Hey guys, im currently using

```
const response = messageCollector.collected.entries().next().value;
```

in order to store messages in a message collector. From this it returns the list/dictionary above. How would I go about retrieving the `content` section of this list?

I tried using

```
console.log(response[0]);
```

Which returns `854408347192786944`. But I can't seem to get anything else from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
response[1].content
```

The response is an array of 2 items. So, `response[0]` is just giving you the string Id in the first position. The rest of the data is in `response[1]`